# NextJS postdev script not running after dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a NextJS project and on the `package.json` file I have a bunch of scripts:

```yaml
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "postdev": "cleanup after dev"
    },
    ...
}
```

I added [`postdev`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) to run some cleanup scripts after `dev` finishes but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when I'm done working, the script doesn't run at all. How do I get `postdev` to run when I exit out of `dev`?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?